# Rails 4.2.6 Glyphicons and JST Issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, jst

Good afternoon all,

I know that there are a lot of questions/answers on stackoverflow regarding Broken Glyphicons with Rails 4 framework. However, none of those solutions are working for me, in addition my JST templates are not updating my view, and no error is being thrown.

See sample code below: (I believe something is wrong with the Asset Pipeline, any tips on troubleshooting would be appreciated.)

**My Environment Configurations**

*Gemfile - sample*

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'ejs'

*application.scss - sample*

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

**update.js.erb**

```
console.log('before jst call');
$('#sample').html(JST["templates/sample_update"](
  {
    name: "<%= @model.name %>",
    phone_number: "<%= @model.phone_no %>"
  })
);
console.log('jst call completed!');
```

Note: The 1st log statement gets printed, the 2nd one doesn't, and no errors are thrown.

**sample_update.jst.ejs**

```
<td><%= name %></td>
<td><%= phone_number %></td>
```

Also, attached is a screenshot of what the Glyphicons look like in Firefox.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I've fixed the JST issue, it was a very silly mistake.
In the application.js, I forgot to include my templates directory.

```
//= require_tree ./templates
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, for those who may have viewed this. The issue was that there was a typo in the html class attribute for the glyphicon element, and therefore nothing was wrong with the Asset Pipeline, it's fine.

'glyphicon' was spelled 'glyhpicon'.